# Missing expression when using REF CURSOR with dynamic SQL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, dynamic-sql

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with dynamic SQL query. I finally got it to compile, but it returns the following error:

> ORA-00936 - Missing expression

Where did I go wrong?

Package spec:

```
TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;

PROCEDURE RADNIK
(
  P_ID_OC_NAJVISA IN RADNIK.ID_NAJVISA_OC%TYPE, --1
  P_IME_PREZIME IN RADNIK.IME%TYPE, --2
  REF_TABELA IN VARCHAR2, --3
  P_ID_OPERATER IN Z_TRANSAKCIJA.ID_OPERATER%TYPE,

  P_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR
);
```

Package body:

```
PROCEDURE RADNIK
(
  P_ID_OC_NAJVISA IN RADNIK.ID_NAJVISA_OC%TYPE,
  P_IME_PREZIME IN RADNIK.IME%TYPE,
  REF_TABELA IN VARCHAR2,
  P_ID_OPERATER IN Z_TRANSAKCIJA.ID_OPERATER%TYPE,

  P_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR
)
IS
  radnikRed RADNIK%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
  'SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
  R.ID_RADNIK,
  R.PREZIME || '' ('' || R.IME_RODITELJA || '') '' || R.IME || '', '' || R.LICNI_BROJ
  IME_PREZIME
  FROM RADNIK R,
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT RT.ID_RADNIK FROM '||REF_TABELA||' RT WHERE RT.ID_OC_NAJVISA='||P_ID_OC_NAJVISA||') RT
    WHERE 
    (R.ID_NAJVISA_OC = '||P_ID_OC_NAJVISA||' and R.STORNO=''N'') OR R.ID_RADNIK=RT.ID_RADNIK)
  WHERE IME_PREZIME LIKE ''%'' || '||P_IME_PREZIME||' || ''%''
  OR '||P_IME_PREZIME||' IS NULL';
  LOOP
    FETCH P_CURSOR INTO radnikRed;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE P_CURSOR; 
END RADNIK;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to tell exactly, but I would suspect some parameter values.

- It might be value of parameter `P_ID_OC_NAJVISA`. What value are you passing there? It looks like you expecting a number there. If not, it might be a problem.
  (What is result of this:  `(R.ID_NAJVISA_OC = '||P_ID_OC_NAJVISA||'` ?)
- It might be also value of `P_IME_PREZIME`. Look how you concatenate `P_IME_PREZIME` . Is it a varchar string or a column name?

If `P_IME_PREZIME` is string then you need instead of:

```
  WHERE IME_PREZIME LIKE ''%'' || '||P_IME_PREZIME||' || ''%''
  OR '||P_IME_PREZIME||' IS NULL';
```

rather this:

```
  WHERE IME_PREZIME LIKE ''%'||P_IME_PREZIME||'%''
  OR '''||P_IME_PREZIME||''' IS NULL';
```

Comment: It will be a number, the value passed from the application is integer. I'm not sure if I understood the second question. It will be true if they are the same, false otherwise. But R.ID_NAJVISA_OC is NUMBER, if it helps any...